# Supersaturated gas solution

Tags: water, solutions, temperature

Can you make a supersaturated gas solution?
As we know solubility decreases when we increase the temperature, So If I do that, will the gas molecules escape the solution or will they stay in the solution and make a supersaturated solution? Or is it just a plain fact that you can't make supersaturated solutions except with solids solutes?

I am kind of leaning towards escaping, because it is hard to keep gas molecules intact with water molecules at high temperatures.

Comment: Observe carefully a bottle of cola :)

Answer (score 3):

Every can of soda, coke etc. is supersaturated with carbon dioxide after opening, i.e. relieving the pressure in the can.

The surface tension of a gas bubble adds to the outside pressure, and more pressure always increases solubility of gases, as you know from Le Chatelier.

Same with gas supersaturated with a condensable gas or solvent with too much solute, you have to overcome the surface tension of small particles or droplets before precipitation can take place.